# Auto Complete Text Box from Access database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, ms-office, ms-access-2010

I have a text box "Textbox1" and a set of 30,000 words stored in an access database. I would like to set the VB Textbox1's auto complete source to the access database. How do I do this in vb.net? I am a novice programmer at present.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sample:

**From an access Database**

[image]

**Create a DataSet in your vb project, connected to that database**

*Add New Item -> Data -> DataSet*

In your `.xsd` designer, add a new TableAdapter, connect it to your Access file, create a query.

[image]

**Query and add them to the TextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'NamesDataSet.Names' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.NamesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.NamesDataSet.Names)

    'get my names from the dataset
    Dim myNames = From n In NamesDataSet.Names Select n.Name

    TextBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
    TextBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource

    'add names to custom list
    TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(myNames.ToArray())
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, still having trouble with this - Main error is 'NamesTableAdapter' is not a member of 'SapiensOpito.Form1. Do you have a source file?

Comment: @JBithell I don't have it anymore... check here about creating dataset and tableadapter. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kda44dwy.aspx